# Trainers who sell as well as train

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-dragonborn

Does anyone know of a list of people in skyrim who train, and also sell things? I have lots of stuff to sell and training while I'm at it would be really helpful.  I know of Gunmar in dragon hold castle (I forget the name) he trains in smithing, and also sells stuff as well.

I can't seem to find a comprehensive list? Anyone know anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full list of trainers capable of serving as merchants is as follows:

### Base Game

- All but one of the trainers at the [College in Winterhold](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_(place)) also sell various magical supplies; typically books related to their school, robes, and soul gems.

  - [Tolfdir](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tolfdir) (Alteration)
  - [Colette Marence](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Colette_Marence) (Restoration)
  - [Drevis Neloren](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Drevis_Neloren) (Illusion)
  - [Faralda](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Faralda) (Destruction)
  - [Phinis Gestor](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Phinis_Gestor) (Conjuration)
  - The one exception is [Sergius Turrianus](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sergius_Turrianus), who doesn't sell anything, despite even having the [Spell Vendor](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spell_Vendor) class.
- In addition, several of the non-College-affiliated, magic-related trainers are also merchants.

  - Conjuration has [Falion](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falion).
  - Destruction has [Sybille Stentor](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sybille_Stentor) and [Wuunferth the unloving](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wuunferth_the_Unliving).
  - Illusion should have [Atub](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atub), but unless you have the Unofficial Skyrim Patch, she is bugged, and not properly added to the factions that would enable this.
- All three Alchemy trainers are also alchemy merchants.

  - [Lami](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lami) in Morthal
  - [Arcadia](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcadia) in Whiterun
  - [Babette](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Babette) in the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary
- Similar to Alchemy, all three Smithing trainers are also blacksmithing merchants:

  - [Ghorza gra-Bagol](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ghorza_gra-Bagol) in Markarth
  - [Balimund](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Balimund) in Riften
  - [Eorlund Gray-Mane](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Eorlund_Gray-Mane)
- There are a few assorted NPCs who are both trainers and merchants outside the above.

  - [Gharol](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gharol) in Dushnikh Yal is a Heavy Armor trainer, and also a blacksmithing merchant.
  - [Grelka](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grelka) in Riften is a Light Armor trainer, and also a merchant of various items, mostly blacksmithing-related.
  - [Ma'jhad](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ma%27jhad), of one of the khajiit trade caravans (going between Windhelm and Solitude), is a Lockpicking trainer, and also a fence with the thieves' Guild.
  - [Revyn Sadri](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Revyn_Sadri) of Windhelm is a Speech Trainer, and also owns a pawn shop.
- Lastly, the following trainers are normally not merchants, but can be [married](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage), which will cause them to open a [small store](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Spouse.27s_Merchandise).

  - [Vilkas](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vilkas) (Two-Handed)
  - [Aela the Huntress](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aela_the_Huntress) (Archery)
  - [Njada Stonearm](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Njada_Stonearm) (Block)
  - [Farkas](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Farkas) (Heavy Armor)
  - [Dravynea the Stoneweaver](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dravynea_the_Stoneweaver) (Alteration)
  - [Scouts-Many-Marshes](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Scouts-Many-Marshes) (Light Armor)

### Dawnguard

[Dawnguard](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) adds three new trainers who are also merchants.

- [Ronthil](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ronthil), a Speech trainer in Volkihar Keep, who sells fairly standard magic-related items
- [Florentius Baenius](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Florentius_Baenius), a Restoration trainer who can be recruited into the Dawnguard, and sells some assorted ingredients, potions, and a couple of spell tomes
- [Sorine Jurard](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sorine_Jurard), an Archery trainer with the Dawnguard who mostly sells crossbows, bolts, and the like.

### Dragonborn

[Dragonborn](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dragonborn) adds three new trainers who are also merchants.

- [Milore Ienth](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Milore_Ienth), an Alchemy trainer in Raven Rock who is also an apothecary
- [Talvas Fathryon](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon), a Conjuration Trainer in Tel Mithryn who also sells tomes and soul gems.
- [Neloth](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Neloth), an Enchanting trainer in Tel Mithryn who also sells staves and soul gems.

Now, this all may be a very large list, but it's unfortunately not a very promising one. The best choices for selling goods to are generally [Fences](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fence_(merchant)#Fences), as they have the most money (depending on your Thieves Guild side job completion), and also buy anything without need for the [Merchant](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Skill_Perks) Perk. But the only Fence who is a Trainer is Ma'jhad, who is part of a Khajiit caravan; if you find yourself needing to wait around for his gold to replenish at any point, he will likely be in a different city when you're done.

Your next best bet is probably going to be a [blacksmith](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blacksmith), as several of them have a thousand gold (including all three who are also trainers), and they buy many of the items you're looting off enemies, even without the Merchant Perk.

Comment: Gunmar of the Dawnguard. Master Smithing trainer and merchant.

Answer (score 3):

Going through the [list of trainers](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Trainer_%28Skyrim%29) on The Elder Scrolls Wikia

## Skyrim

- **[Lami](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lami)** - Alchemy adept trainer; alchemy merchant.
- **[Arcadia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arcadia)** - Alchemy expert trainer; alchemy merchant.
- **[Babette](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Babette)** - Alchemy master trainer; alchemy merchant <sup>1</sup>
- **[Tolfdir](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tolfdir)** - Alteration master trainer; mage supplies (esp. alteration).<sup>2</sup>
- **[Aela the Huntress](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aela_the_Huntress)** - Archery expert trainer; general goods (spouse) <sup>3,M,F</sup>
- **[Njada Stonearm](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Njada_Stonearm)** - Block expert trainer; general goods (spouse) <sup>3,M,F</sup>
- **[Phinis Gestor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Phinis_Gestor)** - Conjuration expert trainer; mage supplies (esp. conjuration) <sup>2</sup>
- **[Sybille Stentor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sybille_Stentor)** - Destruction expert trainer; mage supplies.
- **[Faralda](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Faralda)** - Destruction master trainer; mage supplies. <sup>2</sup>
- **[Gharol](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Gharol)** - Heavy armour expert trainer; blacksmith.
- **[Drevis Neloren](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Drevis_Neloren)** - Illusion master trainer; mage supplies (esp. illusion). <sup>2</sup>
- **[Scouts-Many-Marshes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Scouts-Many-Marshes)** - Light armour adept trainer; general goods (spouse). <sup>M</sup>
- **[Grelka](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Grelka)** - Light armour expert trainer; blacksmith.
- **[Athis](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Athis)** - One handed expert trainer; general goods (spouse). <sup>3,M,F</sup>
- **[Colette Marence](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Colette_Marence)** - Restoration expert trainer; mage goods (esp. restoration). <sup>2</sup>
- **[Ghorza gra-Bagol](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ghorza_gra-Bagol)** - Smithing adept trainer; blacksmith.
- **[Balimund](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Balimund)** - Smithing expert trainer; blacksmith.
- **[Eorlund Gray-Mane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Eorlund_Gray-Mane)** - Smithing master trainer; blacksmith.<sup>3</sup>
- **[Revyn Sadri](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Revyn_Sadri)** - Speech adept trainer; general goods.
- **[Vilkas](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vilkas)** - Two handed master trainer; general goods (spouse)<sup>3,M,F</sup>

## Skyrim: Dawnguard DLC

- [**Sorine Jurard**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sorine_Jurard) - Archery master trainer; general goods<sup>4</sup>.
- **[Florentius Baenius](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Florentius_Baenius)** - Restoration master trainer; alchemy goods.<sup>4</sup>
- **[Ronthil](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ronthil)** Speech adept trainer; general goods. <sup>5</sup>

## Skyrim: Dragonborn DLC

- **[Talvas Fathryon](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talvas_Fathryon)** - Conjuration master trainer; mage supplies.<sup>F</sup>

---

<sup>1: Requires affiliation with Dark Brotherhood. 2: Requires affiliation with College of Winterhold. 3: Requires affiliation with The Companions. 4: Requires affiliation with the Dawnguard.  5: Requires affiliation with the Volkihar clan. M: Only sells if married to the Dragonborn. F: Potential follower (eligible for free training exploit). .</sup>

---

Whilst not all trainers are merchants, most are *near* merchants.  There are possibly a couple of errors in the above either due to me skim reading the articles or to them being not entirely correct - some NPCs were *meant* to be trainers but are bugged, for example.

Comment: you may want to separate out the spouse store trainers since those aren't as useful as the non spouse ones.

Comment: Yeah, I am not interested in those near merchants because the idea is that I spend a lot of money on training then they have lots of money to pay me.

Comment: Gunmar of the Dawnguard. Master Smithing trainer and merchant. Master Neloth( Tel Mithryn on Solstheim) Master Enchanting trainer and merchant.